# Page can’t be found - .razor in razor pages project, Net 5.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, razor-pages, asp.net-core-5.0

I have a razor pages project on Net 5.0. In this project, I would like to use both .cshtml and .razor pages. (maybe with time migrate to .razor). I can successfully use the razor component on .cshtml page, but I can not make the .razor page working, always get "***This page can’t be found***" error.
I followed 
[Combining Razor and Blazor Pages in a Single ASP.NET Core 3 Application](https://mikaelkoskinen.net/post/combining-razor-blazor-pages-single-asp-net-core-3-application) and some others, but still does not work.

**Startup.cs** has

```
services.AddServerSideBlazor();
and
endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
endpoints.MapFallbackToFile("/_Host.cshtml")
```

**_Imports.razor** in root:

```
@using System.Net.Http
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Routing
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web.Virtualization
@using Microsoft.JSInterop
```

**Pages/App.razor**

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Routing 
 <Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Program).Assembly"}">
    <Found Context="routeData">
        <RouteView RouteData="@routeData"/>
    </Found>
    <NotFound>
        <h1>Page not found123</h1>
        <p>Sorry, but there's nothing here!</p>
    </NotFound>
</Router>
```

**Page/_Host.cshtml**

```
@page "/blazor"
 
@{
    Layout = "_Layout";
}
 
<div id="app">
    @(await Html.RenderComponentAsync<App>(RenderMode.Server))
</div>
```

**Page/Shared/_Layout.cshtml**

```
<script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>

 @RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
```

And the page itself: **Pages/Test.razor**

```
@page "/test"
@implements IDisposable
<div>test</div>
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my razor page project structure:

[image]

I add Shared folder to the project,and add App.razor,_Imports.razor to the project.Add Counter.razor,_Host.cshtml to Pages Folder.Add Configuration in Startup.cs.

Startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddServerSideBlazor();
            services.AddRazorPages();
        }
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
                endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            });
        }
```

_Imports.razor(the last two line `RazorPageDemo5._0` is my project name,yours can be `@using projectname @using projectname.Shared`):

```
@using System.Net.Http
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Routing
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web.Virtualization
@using Microsoft.JSInterop
@using RazorPageDemo5._0
@using RazorPageDemo5._0.Shared
```

Page/Shared/_Layout.cshtml:

```
<script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>
    @await RenderSectionAsync("Scripts", required: false)
```

Page/_Host.cshtml(change namespace to your project's):

```
@page "/"
@namespace RazorPageDemo5._0.Pages
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
@{
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <base href="~/" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link href="css/site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <component type="typeof(App)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />

    <div id="blazor-error-ui">
        <environment include="Staging,Production">
            An error has occurred. This application may no longer respond until reloaded.
        </environment>
        <environment include="Development">
            An unhandled exception has occurred. See browser dev tools for details.
        </environment>
        <a href="" class="reload">Reload</a>
        <a class="dismiss"></a>
    </div>

    <script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And then add MainLayout.razor,NavMenu.Razor,SurveyPrompt.razor to Shared folder.Add App.razor to project.

Result:
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer! I was missing MainLayout and Shared folder in root.
May I ask, how does you App.razor look like? Right now I don't get an empty page, but "An unhandled exception has occurred. See browser dev tools for details. Reload "

Comment: Also, when in _Host page "/" there is a conflict with index.cshtml file, I changed it to page "/blazor". Is it ok?

Comment: In console log I see twice "Normalizing '_blazor' to 'http://localhost:63478/_blazor'" and after twice "WebSocket connected to ws://localhost:63478/_blazor?id=" and after "Error: There was an error applying batch 2." and "Error: There was an unhandled exception on the current circuit, so this circuit will be terminated. "

Comment: It is amazing, it is working! But I had to remove  <script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script> from _Host, and leave it only in Layout, otherwise, it was an error.

Comment: I came here looking for guidance. I just want to say I did eventually get things working, however I had to put the pesky <script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script> in the _Host.cshtml file. If someone has tried all other suggestions and its still not working, try moving that line there. One more thing. There are a couple folders in the wwwroot/css folder that need to be coppied over. bootstrap and open-iconic. These styles are needed to render the home page. Just copy em over from a working blazor app.